# Reading database from a file in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a file with full names of workers, birthday, salary etc. For example, this is my text file:

```
John Snow 1967 CEO 3400$ 
Adam Brown 1954 engineer 1200$
```

I need to save this data in separate lists to sort/edit/change/delete. What I have done:

```
userFile = input('Please, enter file name, that you want to open! \n') + '.txt'
workersData = [line.strip() for line in open(userFile, 'r')]
```

I have the following output:

```
['John Snow 1967 CEO 3400$', 'Adam Brown 1954 engineer 1200$']
```

I want to make something like this:

```
worker1 = ['John Snow', '1967', 'CEO', '3400$']
worker2 = [ 'Adam Brown', '1954', 'engineer', '1200$']
workern = ....
```

Or just simply call separate data like:

```
name.worker1 = 'John Snow'
salary.worker2 = '1200'
....
```

I'm just asking if this possible in Python and how to make it correctly

Comment: This is possible. You can `.split()` a string on whitespace. Try it and edit the question if you still have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary:

*Note: I have purposely left out storing the `workers job`, `workers year of birth` and `workers salary` as a task for you*

```
import os

file_path = input("Please, enter the path to the file: ")
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    worker_dict = {}
    k = 1
    for line in open(file_path,'r'):
        split_line = line.split()
        worker = "worker%d" % k
        worker_name = "%s_%s" % (worker, "name")
        worker_yob = "%s_%s" % (worker, "yob") #yob stands for year of birth
        worker_job = "%s_%s" % (worker, "job")
        worker_salary = "%s_%s" % (worker, "salary")
        worker_dict[worker_name] = ' '.join(split_line[0:2])
        # TODO: worker_dict[worker_job] = ...
        # TODO: worker_dict[worker_yob] = ...
        # TODO: worker_dict[worker_salary] = ...
        k += 1
    print(worker_dict)
else:
    print("Error: Invalid file path")
```

**Output (workers_dict only stores the workers name at this point):**

```
Please, enter the path to the file: data.txt
{'worker1_name': 'John Snow', 'worker2_name': 'Adam Brown'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But there is no way to access each value separately like worker2_name etc. ?

Comment: Using `worker_dict.get('worker1_name', None)` allows you to provide a default value if the key is missing, or you could do `worker_dict['worker1_name']` if you dont care about that both would return `'John Snow'`. Can you see how to access `worker2_name` now?

Comment: I was trying worker_dict[worker1_name] without quotes , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This will do your work

```
data = ['John Snow 1967 CEO 3400$', 'Adam Brown 1954 engineer 1200$']
all_workers = []
temp = []
for item in data:
    temp = item.split(" ")
    worker = []
    worker.append(temp[0] + " " + temp[1])
    worker.append(temp[2])
    worker.append(temp[3])
    worker.append(temp[4])
    all_workers.append(worker)
print all_workers
```

Output:

> [['John Snow', '1967', 'CEO', '3400$'], ['Adam Brown', '1954',
>   'engineer', '1200$']]